# How can I check the version of gradle plugin on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

How can I know which version of Gradle plugin I am using in my Eclipse? Please guide.

Comment: https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_find_out_what_plug-ins_have_been_installed%3F

Comment: Thank you but I can't find "About Eclipse Platform" under "help" dropdown but only "About Eclipse" Plus I cannot find "Configuration Details" either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Select 'Help > About Eclipse' (on Macs this is 'Eclipse > About Eclipse').

Click the 'Installation Details' button to display the installation details dialog. Look in the 'Plug-ins' tab to see all the installed plugins.

On recent releases of Eclipse you can select 'Help > Installation Details' to go directly to the installation details dialog.